# How do i add multiple control for this geometry node

Tags: geometry-nodes, empty

I was looking around and found this cool geometry project from RSN 3D's youtube channel, and i wanted to ask that can you make both empty effect both cube at the same time?
edited: or one for the left cube and one for the right cube

thanks

---

PF:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QN7XQZVZhLk1cTQXUqz-b93sTFVClb-u/view?usp=sharing
[image: GIF]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drag these two object infos to your group input like this:

[image]

add a new plane like this:

[image]

add geometry nodes tree with these settings (you only have to change the last entry (object) to your control object:

[image]

result:

[image]

you can mute this node here:

[image]

also double the material and change the empty here:

[image]

Comment: OMGGGGGG this is so cool lol, thanks alot <3 <3

Comment: glad i could help